# How to run gdal.BuildVRT in rasterio?

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, gdalbuildvrt

I'm running some code in Google Colab and I'm using rasterio. I'm trying to do the same thing as the following function, but using rasterio instead (I can't use gdal for this specific project):

```
def write_vrt(items, asset_key, dest_path):
    """Write a VRT with hrefs extracted from a list of items for a specific asset."""
    hrefs = [pc.sign(item.assets[asset_key].href) for item in items]
    vsi_hrefs = [f"/vsicurl/{href}" for href in hrefs]
    gdal.BuildVRT(dest_path, vsi_hrefs).FlushCache()
```

In other words, I'm trying to do the same thing as `gdal.BuildVRT(dest_path, vsi_hrefs).FlushCache()`, but with rasterio.

For context, I'm trying to do the same thing as what's in [this](https://github.com/sweetlhare/STAC-Overflow/blob/main/load_external_data.ipynb) notebook, but with rasterio. If you scroll down halfway, you'll be able to see the `write_vrt` function that I'm trying to modify to work without gdal.

Comment: Not possible. You can manually generate the xml string which mosaics or stacks the input rasters and pass it to rasterio.open though.

Comment: A solution is given in  [dev@rasterio.groups.io](https://rasterio.groups.io/g/dev/topic/28023471)

Comment: I don't think that link provides a solution. It just shows how to get VRT xml string for a single raster, still need to manually generate the xml string which mosaics or stacks all input rasters.

Comment: Can you perhaps explain more why you cannot use gdal? Since rasterio is built on gdal anyway? Any environment that you have rasterio you would automatically have gdal?

Comment: At a minimum, you shouldn't use rasterio and gdal in the same Python program. According to the rasterio [docs](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/switch.html#mutual-incompatibilities): "Unless you have deep knowledge about both packages, choose exactly one of import osgeo.gdal or import rasterio. GDAL's bindings (gdal for the rest of this document) and Rasterio are not entirely compatible and should not, without a great deal of care, be imported and used in a single Python program."

Comment: @JaschaMuller yeah gboeing is correct. That was partially the reason why. The other reason is because GDAL takes a long time to install on a Google Colab instance and the installation sometimes fails. This made it impractical.

However, I was able to resolve this issue by installing gdal in the notebook, running the code that needed GDAL (I only needed to run this once since I'm just creating supplementary data), and then I no longer needed to install or run GDAL. Luckily, there was no conflict between rasterio and GDAL in my code!

Comment: @gboeing I was able to resolve the issue as you can see above. I'm still working on training models on the new data, but here's the notebook if interested: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17K-gXacwxdgW6PAt5cpCpGi-dplg2IrH?usp=sharing